# Как типизировать мой react-hook-form код

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
import Button from "../button/Button"
import Input from "../input/Input"
import { useForm, FormProvider, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form"

export const SignInForm = () => {
   interface IFormValues {
      email: string;
      password: string;
    }


   const methods = useForm()
   const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormValues> = (data: IFormValues, event?) => {
      event?.preventDefault()
      console.log(data)
   }

   return (
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
         <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit())}>
            <h1>Авторизация</h1>
            <h2>Получите доступ к своему профилю</h2>
            <p>Эл-почта:</p>
            <Input type='email' placeholder='Email' name='email' />
            <p>Пароль:</p>
            <Input type='password' placeholder='Пароль' name='password' />
            <Button type='filledLight' text='Войти' />
         </form>
      </FormProvider>
   )
}

export default SignInForm
```

Сделал форму с помощью своих кастомных инпутов и кастомной кнопки, как сделать типизацию этого всего на react-hook-form.